type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' while mockito test and auto_mappr
I want to test a repository function which contains a convertList call generated by auto_mappr. When I run the test a type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' is thrown.
So I created a minimal example to test it:
entity_mappr.dart:
import 'package:auto_mappr_annotation/auto_mappr_annotation.dart';
import 'entity_mappr.auto_mappr.dart';

class Entity {}
class Model {}

@AutoMappr([
    MapType<Entity, Model>(),
    MapType<Model, Entity>(),
])
class Mappr extends $Mappr {}

class Runner {
    late Mappr mappr = Mappr();
    List<Model> call(List<Entity> list) {
        return mappr.convertList(list);
    }
}

entity_mappr_test.dart:
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_full_width/entity_mappr.dart';

@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<Mappr>()])
import 'entity_mappr_test.mocks.dart';

void main() {
    final list = List<Entity>.from([Entity(), Entity()]);
    final mappr = MockMappr();
    final runner = Runner()..mappr = mappr;
    group('Mappr', () {
        test('call() should return a list of Model instances', () {
        when(mappr.convertList(list))
            .thenReturn(List<Model>.from([Model(), Model()]));
        final result = runner.call(list);
        expect(result, isA<List<Model>>());
        expect(result.length, 2);
        expect(result[0], isA<Model>());
        expect(result[1], isA<Model>());
        });
    });
}


How can I test the call function?
Why is this exception being thrown?

Thank you for your help!

I had found a solution by overwriting the method:
class MyMockMappr extends MockMappr {
@override
List convertList<SOURCE, TARGET>(Iterable<SOURCE?> model) {
return super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#convertList, [model]),
returnValue: List.from([])) as List;
}
}

Seems like a bug that Mockito isn't generating an override itself.  I recommend filing a bug.
